# Call to undefined method "Connect"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, database-connection, multi-tenant

I'm working in a multi-tenant system, I previously tried the https://github.com/hyn/multi- tenant package but in the end I decided to do this implementation with my own method. After a lot of research and testing different things I have managed to build this code, but when I execute it tells me that the connect method is not defined, here I leave what I have done, most likely this is due to some nonsense that I has overlooked, but if someone can help me solve this I would greatly appreciate it

helpers:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

if(! function_exists('conexionBD')){
 /**
     * Establish a tenant database connection.
     *
     * @param $hostname
     * @param $username
     * @param $password
     * @param $database
     */

    function conexionBD($hostname, $username, $password, $database){
        DB::purge('empresa');

        Config::set('database.connections.empresa.host', $hostname);
        Config::set('database.connections.empresa.database', $database);
        Config::set('database.connections.empresa.username', $username);
        Config::set('database.connections.empresa.password', $password);

        DB::reconnect('empresa');

        Schema::connection('empresa')->getConnection()->reconnect();
    }
}
```

Empresa Model:

```
class empresa extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'hostname',
        'username',
        'password',
        'database'
    ];

    public function ciudad() {
        return $this->belongsTo('confia\ciudad');
    }

    public function empresaUsuario() {
        return $this->hasMany('confia\empresasUsuario');
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        if (! $this->connected()) {
            conexionBD(
                $this->hostname,
                $this->username,
                $this->password,
                $this->database
            );
        }
    }
    /**
     * Check if the current tenant connection settings matches the company's database settings.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function connected()
    {
        $connection = Config::get('database.connections.empresa');
        return $connection['username'] == $this->username &&
            $connection['password'] == $this->password &&
            $connection['database'] == $this->database;
    }
}
```

Middleware Tenant:

```
use Closure;
use confia\empresa;

class Tenant{

    protected $company;

    /**
     * Tenant Conctructor
     * @param empresa $empresa
     */

    public function __construct(empresa $empresa)
    {
        $this->empresa = $empresa;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        if (($request->session()->get('empresaId')) === null)
            return redirect()->route('inicio')->withErrors(['error' => __('Por favor inicie sesión en alguna empresa antes de intentar esta acción')]);

        // Get the company object with the id stored in session
        $empresa= $this->empresa->find($request->session()->get('empresaId'));

        // Connect and place the $company object in the view
        $this->connect($empresa);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

In my session variable empresaId I have stored the ID of my company concat to a static string, this is what gives me the name of the database associated with that company.

When I run the system, at the time of making the change of tenant to start working with another database, I get the following error,

"Call to undefined method app\Http\Middleware\Tenant::connect()"

Someone knows that my code is missing or that I am doing wrong to make the multi-tenant system work correctly?

Comment: why are u passing $empresa to the connect method? when the connect does not require a param. and why dont u try $empresa->connect();

Comment: Do you have the stack from this error? Theres a call to a static method "connect" inside Tenant class, but I can't see this method in the code you posted.

Comment: I changed the code of my middleware and that error no longer appears, but now it happens to me that I am not doing the configuration of the database, even though in my table of companies in the database it has all the correct values to do the configuration, the new error I'm getting is SQLSTATE [3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected